# why does this recursive program for factorial not work?

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

Below is the code, please pin point exactly where i am wrong.
I have declared, defined the function, i don't know what is wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int factorial(int b); /* Declaration */


int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("%d",factorial(num));
    return 0;
}

int factorial(int b) /*Function definition*/
{

    return b*factorial(b-1);

}
```

Comment: Do not spam with tags please. This is not C#

Comment: What debugging attempts have you made? Hint: what should the value of `factorial(0)` be?

Comment: Related, the root problem is a direct duplicate of *many* recursive questions on this site, [including **this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058449/recursive-factorial-program-in-c-hangs-when-executing). You have no base-case to stop the recursion chain. Unrelated, even after you fix this I suggest you consider what malaise will transpire upon someone entering  `-1` (or any negative value), which is completely legitimate to fulfill your input requirements. Something wicked, this way comes.

Comment: `"i don't know what is wrong"` - Start by identifying why you *think* something is wrong.  What actual indication of a problem do you have?

Comment: To figure out what's wrong by yourself, you can print variables as the program runs to see whether the program is doing what you expect.  E.g., you could add `printf("factorial called with %d\n", b);` to the beginning of the `factorial` function and you would see the problem.  Stepping through the code with a debugger is even better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to end the recursion at some point:

```
int factorial(int b) /*Function definition*/
{
    if (b == 0) return 1;
    return b*factorial(b-1);

}
```

Comment: So how about -1...

Comment: Factorials are not defined for negative numbers, so 'unsigned int' would be the more appropriate date type...